# How do i stop a button from time counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button when clicked its starts the count right so now i want it to stop the count when clicked again. so i that ican be able to click any other button and that button must do exactly as the first one 
any will be much appreciated.

This is how the button created

```
     function createButtons(tbID, tbClass, tbType, tbValue, onClick) {
      return '\n<input '
            + (tbID ? ' id=\'' + tbID + '\'' : '')
            + (tbClass ? ' class=\'' + tbClass + '\'' : '')
            + (tbType ? ' type=\'' + tbType + '\'' : '')
            + (tbValue ? ' value=\'' + tbValue + '\'' : '')
            + (onClick ? ' onclick=\'toggle(this);' + onClick + '\'' : '')
            + '>';
     }

      function (i, item) {
       newContent += createButtons("tb" + item.CommonCable, null, "submit",         item.CommonCable, toggle);
        });
```

The following code is counting the time when button clicked. and display it in an HTML page.
         function toggle(ths) {

```
       $(ths).toggleClass("btnColor");
       $("#tb").toggleClass("btnColorR");
       var clicked = $(ths).val();

      $("#setCount").html(" DOWNTIME TYPE : " + clicked + " MINUTES : " + minutes + "         SECONDS : " + count );
       count = count + 1;

        if (count % 60 == 0) {
           minutes += 1;
            count = 0;
        }
           timer = setTimeout("toggle()", 1000);
    }
```

Comment: `ths` should not be `this` ? Simply check if the btn `hasClass` counting, if it does stop the counter with `clearInterval(timer)`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add an onClick handler to the stop button, with the following line inside:

```
timer = null;
```